# How to Ant build with project lombok library?

Tags: ant, lombok

Has anyone build project (containing project Lombok annotations) with ant build?

I have added lombok.jar in classpath, but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Possible problems:

1. You're not actually including the jar file in classpath. Worth checking it twice.
2. You are including the jar, but annotation processing is off. This 
   would happen if you're compiling with javac5 or earlier. Use javac6 
   and make sure there's nothing like -proc:none being passed as 
   argument.